# I can't identify a word from one video

Tags: listening

The text is:

“I didn’t receive **...** I found Kevin or any part of Kevin, so I have places like this to help me heal.”

**...** is the word I can't catch it. who can help me identify it?

[The video link](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTQ5Nzc5OTIw.html), password is **goodgood** , input it in the text-box in the middle of video box,and click the button next to the text-box.

Sorry I can only upload it to chinese website.

Comment: Sorry, the video link is :  http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTQ5Nzc5OTIw.html ,you can input goodgood in the textbox in the middle of video box,and click the button next to the textbox.  Sorry I can only upload it to chinese website.

Comment: @Raghav *textbox* is fine; *text-box* is not, *text box* is preferred. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=text-box%2Ctextbox&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like she wants to say:

> “I didn't receive a call that...Kevin was found...”

but then she says:

> “I didn't receive a call that...Kev...that I found Kevin or any part of Kevin...”

Comment: Thank you!  But these is not stop after Kev.It is too continuous.  Is is a normal speak way?